# Meteor JS and working with Client-Side Persistence

Tags: jquery, xml, meteor

I am working on an app that will plot out locations on a Google Map (using their Google Maps API) and the markers that get plotted will be clickable (along with some kind of UI craziness).

I am marching into unfamiliar territory (newb alert) when it comes to working with Meteor.JS and client-side persistence. The app is consuming an XML web service that spits back postings (let's say for cat recitals). The only bit of information that is sent back in regards to a location is the City & State (no LAT or LONG). So, I have to use Google's GeoLocation API to look up the Lat/LNG to then plot a marker on my google map.

I am going to be preloading like 15 recitals and am not wanting to make the API call(s) every time the page loads. I am simply wanting to just store the LAT/LNG so that I can spit out a google map relatively quickly. How can I go about doing this?

The XML will look something like this:

```
<recitals>
  <recital>
    <location>Mesa, AZ</location>
    <date>2014-1-19 1:31 AM</date>
  </recital>
</recitals>
```

Comment: Meteor comes with [amplify](http://docs.meteor.com/#amplify) for reading and writing to local storage. The docs can be found [here](http://amplifyjs.com/). I use it in one of our projects, and it seems pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with client-side data is local storage:

```
window.localStorage['banana'] = {
    type: 'fruit',
    color: 'yellow',
}

window.localStorage['banana'].curvature = 2.71;
```

It works in [almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage). If you need to worry about yet older ones, use [amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/). First, add it to your project:

```
mrt add amplify
```

Then use it similarly:

```
amplify.store('banana', {
    type: 'fruit',
    color: 'yellow',
});

amplify.store('banana');
```

Comment: Thanks Hubert! What is `mrt`? I have always just used the command `meteor add xxxxx`

Comment: It's Meteorite - a package system for Meteor. If you don't use it yet, start today. `meteor add` works for official packages only, while meteorite gives you access to whole community package directory. [Here](http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/) are instructions, and [here](http://atmosphere.meteor.com/) is the package database.

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna switch my app over now :)